# Energy consumption per bit (in joules) in a LDPC encoder

Tags: ldpc

Can we frame a mathematical model based on the clock frequency (CPU cycles), to compute the energy consumption per bit for a LDPC encoder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we frame a mathematical model based on the clock frequency (CPU cycles), to compute the energy consumption per bit for a LDPC encoder?

Not really. Energy consumption (in Joule) implies a physical device and the energy consumption will vary hugely with the properties of the device itself regardless of what algorithm you are running.  For example the energy difference between running the encoder on a desktop computer in Matlab or on a dedicated low-power ASIC will result be several orders of magnitude even if they run at the same  bitrate.

What you CAN do is

1. Estimate the number of CPU instructions per bits by analyzing the algorithm and the instruction set of the processor.
2. Measure the incremental power consumption for different CPU loads on your target platform
3. Calculate the incremental energy consumption of the encoder for different bit rates.

Obviously, this only is useful if you already have a target platform.

Comment: 100% this. Also, it's pretty important to understand how the encoder fits the *specific* architecture. Artificial example: your encoding matrix has structure allowing for the info word × matrix multiplication to be done block wise with block sizes of 64×64. Your CPU has SIMD units that can deal with 64 (short) integers at once. Win! Your CPU's SIMD width is only half that – you go with a different encoder alltogether; it's not that you need, say, four times as many instructions, you might simply go for a different structure for binary vector × matrix products altogether.

Comment: If I use a open source simulator (OAI 5GNR ULSIM/DLSIM), how to use it to compute the energy consumption if LDPC encoder is implemented in c language.

Comment: as Hilmar actually explained: not at all.